# Fix Steam In-game Overlay on Mac OSX

Tags: steam, macos

For quite some time Steam has been showing a popup asking me to grant Steam accessibility privileges to enable the in-game overlay even though I already did this.

I have tried reinstalling steam, uninstalling my steam skin (air) and removing the privilege and re-adding it.

Comment: You do not need to include signatures in your post. That's what the box at the bottom is for.